# how to set array of date to fireDate in local notification at a time

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10, uilocalnotification

Actually in my app I'm starting more than two timers at different times. After certain time intervals I want notifications to fire. It's working fine when the app is on foreground but not in the background. How can I solve this?

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Add your code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do following...

[image]

You need to turn on background mode.

In AppDelegate, Add this code to run app in background

Create a property

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTask;
```

and then do following...

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    self.backgroundTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        DLOG(@"End of tolerate time. Application should be suspended now if we do not ask more 'tolerance'");

    }];

    if (self.backgroundTask == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
        DLOG(@"This application does not support background mode");
    } else {
        //if application supports background mode, we'll see this log.
        DLOG(@"Application will continue to run in background");
    }

}
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Welcome @Goneshkr :)

Comment: how to Extend background execution time in iOS 10. now it's working only 3 min.  using  "beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler"

Answer (score 0):

you can handle with both timer into this appdelgate method

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
}
```

when app going to background that time this method is called and your code still execute into this method, Hope this will help you.

**Note : first enable background mode into Project Target -> Availability Tab -> Background Modes -> ON**

Comment: Can i call timer method in  applicationDidEnterBackground ?

Comment: Yes , you can call timer method,but if you can create method in other viewcontroller than you have to change code into appdelegate and create method on appdelegate and call method other class using appdelegate instance.

Comment: Actually i  created timer method in homeViewController. and I'm calling that method in appDelegate like  using homeVC reference var                                                              'func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        
        homeVC.updateTime()
    
    } '
it's not working

Comment: @Goneshkr create method in Appdelegate and if needed then call method in Homeviewcontroller Ex. "updateTime" method create and implement on Appdelegate and call applicationDidEnterBackground and also homeviewcontroller using Appdelegate instance. so it's work expected.