# Background image (Background Mode) uploading in Amazon S3 bucket without using AWS SDK in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, swift2

I have an application that capture image/images, the request is fired for getting the document upload policies, and uploading the image/images starts. When user is in the foreground the image/images uploads but when user is in the background the image/images do not gets uploaded or failed to upload. So I want to upload the image/images when the application is in the background (Background Mode).

What is the right path to follow for the Background (Background Mode) Uploading of the image/images?

The application is written in Swift 2.3

Any Help would be Appriciated

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "Background Uploading"? I mean image uploading in another thread(other than main thread) OR  background mode (when app is in background)

Comment: Background Mode

Comment: It might help you... check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647210/how-to-set-array-of-date-to-firedate-in-local-notification-at-a-time/42647482#42647482

Comment: Thanks Richard for the help !! But Its clearly mentioned that i am using Swift 2.3

Comment: It doesn't matter which language you are using...you just need to turn on the Background Mode from Capabilities in your target...and write some line of code. thats it !! :)

Comment: Anyone has any solution of this, I am also facing the same.

Answer (score 3):

Use AWSS3TransferUtility which handles background uploads

```
    import AWSS3

    let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
    //In order to customize the header information, we use the AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression class
    let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression()

    //We want our file to be publicly available by default
    expression.setValue("public-read", forRequestParameter: "x-amz-acl")

    //Copy the custom Meta information into the expression
    transferUtility.uploadFile(uploadRequest.body, bucket: uploadRequest.bucket ?? "", key: uploadRequest.key ?? "", contentType: uploadRequest.contentType ?? "", expression: expression) { (task, error) in }
```

Dont forget to add below code in your app delegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    /*
     Store the completion handler.
     */
    AWSS3TransferUtility.interceptApplication(application, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession: identifier, completionHandler: completionHandler)
}
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I needed for my app. For anyone else looking there is some sample code from Amazon featured here (albeit a tad dated but still useful) https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/amazon-s3-transfer-utility-for-ios/